# OpenSessionInView filter conversion from Spring 2.5 to Spring 4

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm converting an old SpringMVC application that uses Spring 2.5 to Spring 4.  I cannot get the OpenSessionInView filter to work, which was working well in 2.5.

My situation is that I've got an command object, returned in a Request GET, that is then stored in the Session.  This form is POSTed.  Some service layer code then attempts to read a collection from the command object that had not been fetched initially, leading to a `LazyInitializationException`.

The error I keep getting is:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.abc.model.Entity1.details, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

....

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The `hibernateFilter` is listed first in the `<filter-mapping>` order.

In my Hibernate.Xml I've got the following:

```
<alias name="abcSessionFactory" alias="commonSessionFactory"/>
<alias name="abcSessionFactory" alias="instrSessionFactory"/>
<alias name="abcSessionFactory" alias="sessionFactory"/>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="abcSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="abcDataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:/org/abc/model/*.xml</value>
            <value>classpath*:/org/abc/common/model/*.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.OSCacheProvider</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="abcSessionFactory"/>
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>

<alias name="txManager" alias="transactionManager"/>
```

I would imagine that there must be more to the configuration, but I'm at a loss.

I tried using the `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` property, and this did work.  But it feels like such a total hack and so I'd really like to figure out how to get the OpenSessionInViewFilter to work.

Edit:

From OpenSessionInViewFilter:

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = lookupSessionFactory(request);
    boolean participate = false;

    WebAsyncManager asyncManager = WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(request);
    String key = getAlreadyFilteredAttributeName();

    if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.hasResource(sessionFactory)) {
        // Do not modify the Session: just set the participate flag.
        participate = true;
    }
    else {
        boolean isFirstRequest = !isAsyncDispatch(request);
        if (isFirstRequest || !applySessionBindingInterceptor(asyncManager, key)) {
            logger.debug("Opening Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter");
            Session session = openSession(sessionFactory);
            SessionHolder sessionHolder = new SessionHolder(session);
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, sessionHolder);

            AsyncRequestInterceptor interceptor = new AsyncRequestInterceptor(sessionFactory, sessionHolder);
            asyncManager.registerCallableInterceptor(key, interceptor);
            asyncManager.registerDeferredResultInterceptor(key, interceptor);
        }
    }
```

Tracing through here, the `session` object is created and seems fine.

Later in my Controller code the `PersistentSet` code is called to try to load the collection in question.  From `AbstractPersistentCollection`:

```
private <T> T withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(LazyInitializationWork<T> lazyInitializationWork) {
    SessionImplementor originalSession = null;
    boolean isTempSession = false;
    boolean isJTA = false;

    if ( session == null ) {
        if ( allowLoadOutsideTransaction ) {
            session = openTemporarySessionForLoading();
            isTempSession = true;
        }
        else {
            throwLazyInitializationException( "could not initialize proxy - no Session" );
        }
    }
    else if ( !session.isOpen() ) {

...
...
```

The `session` is null, and `allowLoadOutsideTransaction` is `false`.  This is where the Exception I'm getting is being thrown.

I'm not familiar enough to know if the `session` is supposed to be null or not here, or if the `allowOutsideTransaction` is the problem.

Comment: Although you did not mentioned the method from where you are starting the transaction. But if you will mark it to @Transactional you will not required this filter also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OpenSessionInViewFilter` keeps the session for the scope of the request.  You're talking about keeping for two requests, which is problematic.

You should re-retrieve the object from hibernate or you could `evict` the object during the GET request handling and then `update` it to "re-attach" it to the session during the POST.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It's more a matter of trying to get the `OpenSessionInViewFilter` to work because it was working in 2.5 and there's lots of code that's evidently dependent on it working.  It's hard to identify where all those spots are in the code.  And so rather than going through and trying to find all of those either by waiting for errors to pop up or doing time-consuming exhaustive analysis, it's probably easier just to try to get the `OpenSessionInViewFilter` working.

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed then where `OpenSessionInViewFilter` isn't working?  The scenario you describe above, a session appearing to be valid across multiple requests, indicates something else was going on, `OpenSessionInViewFilter` won't do this and, to my knowledge, never has.